# Running jupyter notebook cells as an interactive SLURM job on VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, slurm, hpc

I am doing some analyses using vscode on a remote server that has got SLURM installed to manage jobs and provide parallel computing. I would like to run each cell in the Jupyter notebook as an interactive job on SLURM the same way my command line code would be run as an interactive SLURM job after I have used `srun` to request compute nodes. The jobs I need to run on the Jupyter notebook require a lot of memory, so I need to run them using SLURM.

My current work around is to run `srun` on the terminal and start a python terminal, then I copy and paste the code from each cell of my notebook into the python terminal. I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but answering as I also came across this problem recentrly.

After you do `srun` on a terminal, you should be able to `ssh` directly into your compute node in VScode and use all the capabilities of the compute node in the interactive mode/notebook

The steps I take, for example, are:

1. in a terminal (e.g. powershell), `srun` into a node
2. add that node to your `config` file, so that you can ssh into it
3. open vscode and ssh into that node
4. run code in interactive window/notebook, with access to CPU/GPU of the node

Answer (score 0):

A well-suited solution to this challenge is utilizing the **Submitit** library ([github repository](https://github.com/facebookincubator/submitit)). This library is designed to interface with SLURM, facilitating the submission of Python functions as jobs from your notebooks.

A pretty simple test example taken from [Oakland University page](https://kb.oakland.edu/uts/HPCJupyterSLURM) would be:

```
import submitit
import sys
import os

def primes(nprimes):
  os.system('module load Python')
  n = nprimes
  for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print (p),
  print ('Done')

log_folder = "log_test/%j"
executor = submitit.AutoExecutor(folder=log_folder)
executor.update_parameters(slurm_job_name="PrimesTest", tasks_per_node=1, 
nodes=1, gpus_per_node=1, timeout_min=300, slurm_partition="defq")
job = executor.submit(primes, 1000000)
print(job.job_id)  # ID of your job
output = job.result()
```